# Writing an algorithm to reverse a string with a loop?

Tags: swift, algorithm

I need to make a function that will reverse the string a type in. I cannot use the .reverse() function at all. This has to be an algorithm using a loop

This is what I have so far but the loop is not executing ... I am working in swift playgrounds for this. Thanks in advance

```
   func reverse(_ phrase: String) -> String
{
    var phraseArray = [phrase.characters]
    var reverseString = ""
    for i in phrase.characters{
        var character = phrase.characters.last 
        reverseString += String(describing: character)
        phraseArray.removeLast()

    }
    return reverseString
}
```

Comment: ```The code won't work``` is not the most useful description.

Comment: Note to potential answerers: Seeing as this is almost certainly a homework question, do not provide a direct solution, as per Stackoverflow's policy on homework questions

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) before asking your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues here:

1. `phraseArray` is an array containing a single element, the `String.CharacterView` instance returned by `phrase.characters`. If you want to make a new array containing the characters of the character view, then pass the character view into the array initializer. Also, it would be more appropriate to call this something like `characters`:

   ```
   var characters = Array(phrase.characters)
   ```
2. `phrase.characters.last` will always return the same character, because neither `phrase` or its `characters` are being changed between iterations.
3. As a consequence of point 1, `phraseArray.removeLast()` will remove the single character view it was populated with, **not** a character from the characters of the character view. Once you make the change in point 1, you can use `characters.removeLast()` to remove the last character, *and* have it returned by the `removeLast()` function. You can use this returned value to replace `phrase.characters.last`.

Implement these changes, and see how it goes. Let me know if you run into further issues.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the answer for you. But I can describe the algorithm:
You need to:

1. Get the string to become a character array
2. iterate over *half* the array, doesn't matter if you start from the
   beginning or from the end
3. on each iteration switch the character that your loop's index points
   to with the character that is index's value from the other end of
   the string. So if you start from the beginning it would be 0 and last,
   then 1 and last - 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
   func reverse(_ phrase: String) -> String
{
    var phraseArray = Array(phrase.characters)

    var rev = [Character]()
    var len = phraseArray.count
    for i in 0..<len {
        rev.append(phraseArray.removeLast())
    }

    return String(rev)
}

print(reverse("AB"))
```

Comment: For me, I won't vote down your answer because it's not wrong and I assume that it does answers the OP's question. However, as a professional community for programming, answering such a question is not big deal at all, it is clear that the OP is asking about solving a homework, if I would answer it, I would try to let my answer to provide some logic to the OP as same as other answer do, to give him the ability to solve it. That does not mean we are the bad guys that we hate to help, I think it is the opposite when letting the OP think about solving it a little bit, it does worth it for him...